# Python 3.5.1 (AMD64) ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'OverflowError'>: int too long to convert

Tags: python, windows-10, ctypes

I'm using `Python 3.5.1 (AMD64)` on `WIN32`.

I'm running the code in `Windows 10`
Any suggestions how to fix the error?

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'OverflowError'>: int too long to convert
```

Comment: Don't pass it too big an integer?

Comment: The default argument conversion is to a 32-bit C `int`. You're lucky to be on 64-bit Windows in this case, which catches the error. The intermediate conversion is to a C `long`, which is 32-bit on Windows, so Python catches the overflow. On 64-bit Unix a C `long` is 64-bit, so you wouldn't get an obvious exception, and the converted value would be silently truncated as a 32-bit `int`.

Comment: If you're passing a pointer or large integer, then you must declare the function's `argtypes`. You should do that anyway for safety and sanity. The same applies to `restype` if a function returns a pointer or large integer.

Answer (score 1):

For me two approaches worked to prevent this:

Lets say we have this function:

```cpp
USB_GetDeviceInterfaceList(QWORD DeviceId, BYTE *pInterfaceList, DWORD *pdwInterfaceAmount)
```

The this would work:

**General shared code:**

```python
from ctypes import *
slibc = 'lib\\usb.dll'
libc = CDLL(slibc)

interface_list = (c_byte * 128)()
interface_amount = c_int()
```

**First approach, defining argtypes:**

```python
ctypes.libc.USB_GetDeviceInterfaceList.argtypes = [c_int64, POINTER(c_byte * 128), POINTER(c_int)]
libc.USB_GetDeviceInterfaceList(2425014470954602011, byref(interface_list), byref(interface_amount))
```

**Second approach, using typecasting:**

```python
libc.USB_GetDeviceInterfaceList(c_int64(2425014470954602011), byref(interface_list), byref(interface_amount))
```